# Чи потрібен пробіл між цифрою і значками відсотка чи градуса?

Tags: орфографія, разом-дефіс-окремо

В редакційній практиці не існує єдиного підходу до відділення символів «%» і «°» від попередньої цифри (числа) пробілом, подібно до того, якби замість «%» або «°» було записано слово «відсоток» («градус») у відповідному відмінку. Практика такого відбиття остаточно не прижилася...

**То як бути?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Коротко:** писати [нерозривний] пробіл.

---

Одразу чесно скажу, не можу віднайти весь мережевного [ДСТУ](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8) на затвердженій іменці. Але деякі посилання на нього маються [на Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83).

> Відповідно до пункту 6.15 ДСТУ 3651.1-97 позначення одиниці треба розташовувати в одному рядку з числовим значенням величини, без перенесення на наступний рядок. Між числом і позначенням одиниці залишають проміжок. Тому потрібно писати 15 °C, 20 %, 130 К, 5 м.

Цебто між числами та знаком [нерозривний проміж](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB).

---

Подібне запитання: [Де ставити знак відсотків тут “40-70”](/questions/2864/)